# keras multiple input (images) does not work

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I'm new in Keras but as I understand It's possible to make network with 2 input and one output. I'm trying to compare two images and get camera movements in output layer. here is my code

```
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='softmax', input_shape=(64, 64, 3)))
model1.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='softmax'))
model1.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model1.add(Dropout(0.5))
model1.add(Flatten())
model1.add(Dense(64))

model2 = Sequential()
model2.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='softmax', input_shape=(64, 64, 3)))
model2.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='softmax'))
model2.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model2.add(Dropout(0.5))
model2.add(Flatten())
model2.add(Dense(64))

merged = Merge([model1, model2], mode='concat', concat_axis=-1)
model = Sequential()
model.add(merged)

model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='softmax'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.5, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=sgd)

model.fit([X1, X2], Y, batch_size=32, epochs=100,callbacks=[callback])
```

X1 and X2 are the two list of images. I expect to find movement from X1[i] to X2[i]

Y is something like this:

```
Y = np.array([[0.12, 0, 0.6],
              [0.4, 0, 0.6],
              [0.6, 0.17, 0],...
```

it trained well but the result is fixed for all the input data
,such as :

```
[[ 0.26296708  0.38299543  0.35403749]
 [ 0.26296708  0.38299543  0.35403746]
 [ 0.26296708  0.38299543  0.35403746],...]
```

any idea?